# KendoUI get Color of one/more bars of the BarChart with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a bar chart like in this demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/column

I want to get all colors of the generated bars with js.
Something like this:

```
function getColors() {  
  for (i=0:bars.Count) {
    colorArray[i] = $('#chart').data("kendoChart").options.series[0].data[I].usercolor TODO?? how to access the bars
  }
}
```

**Additionally**: How to set one/more colors of a pie chart with javascript: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pie-charts/index

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default chart colours, why not choose the colours you want?

You can do this specifying the [SeriesColors](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/ChartBuilder#methods-SeriesColors(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.String>)) when you define your Kendo MVC bar chart e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart().
              .Name("Chart")
              .SeriesColors("#f00", "#0f0", "#00f", "#f0f")
)
```

To do this using [JavaScript](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-seriesColors):

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  seriesColors: ["red", "green"],
  series: [
    { data: [1, 2] },
    { data: [1, 2] },
    { data: [1, 2] }
  ]
});
</script>
```